# Is it possible to detect a Whatsapp voice call ended in Android?

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-audiomanager

I would like to listen when Whatsapp voice call ended.

If the app was granted to access notification listener, I can detect an incoming WhatsApp call by parsing notification data but there are no data when a call ended.

So is there any solutions for this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also detect if the call is ongoing... because the notification will be posted to the listener every second ( Because the call duration info in notification changes
every second ) until the call ends. Just start a timer process to detect the last time a WhatsApp call notification was detected , and if the time is greater than 3 seconds, you can declare that as an ending of a call and run your code there.

Comment: Hi, I can see the duration info on notification bar while the call is ongoing but how can I read this information from Notification. I tried read data from notification extras  with Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT and Notification.EXTRA_CHRONOMETER_COUNT_DOWN but it not work.